# How to use my custom button when creating SSO with the Google Identity Services for Web?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-oauth, single-sign-on, google-signin

I'm trying to create google sso popup flow in my react/Nextjs web app.

However, by following the guidelines by Google with the [Google Identity Services for Web](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/display-button), all I can I use is a bare minimum branded button provided by Google:

[image]

QUESTION: **I wonder how can I use my own custom button to trigger the same popup for selecting account?**

I'm welcome to any other options if not deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google OAuth2.0 url for your custom button.

First, get a client_id for your web application-  https://console.cloud.google.com

Replace window url on button click.

There are many ways to do that, you can use window.location.replace('your_google_auth_url')

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?scope=https%3A//www.googleapis.com/auth/businesscommunications https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https%3A//www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage&access_type=offline&prompt=consent&include_granted_scopes=true&response_type=code&state=state_parameter_passthrough_value&redirect_uri="your-app-redirect-url"&client_id="your_google_app_client_id"
```

Above is the oauth2 url. You need to provide client_id, redirect_url and scope you need.

Scope is a permission, if you need users email info you need to add `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` this scope, etc.

You can find all the scopes here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes

Example: [Google OAuth2 API v2](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth/oauthchooseaccount?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Foauthplayground&prompt=consent&response_type=code&client_id=407408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile%20openid&access_type=offline&service=lso&o2v=2&flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for myself:

use `initTokenClient` and `requestAccessToken` to retrieve access token with the prompt.

https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/use-token-model#how_to_handle_consent

And then retrieve email (usually in server) by requesting google api `'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo'` with the bearer access token .